# "adobe flash player has stopped a potentially unsafe operation" in HTML Flash loaded

Tags: html, object, embed, flash

I am getting error "adobe flash player has stopped a potentially unsafe operation" when I loaded HTML Flash Browser.

When I embed swf in html with object code & used in website, it is not displayed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on Settings and Edit locations to add the SWF Location

Reference from Adobe:

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/communicate-internet-flash-content.html

Answer (score 0):

When i face this problem, i change this

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
```

to

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never" />
```

This problem causes only local flash applications